# How to replica my input value to next input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two input boxes, Where when i enter in one input box, it replica should be in the next input box.

For that i'm setting state of field2 with the value coming from field1

I tried the following but i'm getting undefined (in console if i log the next value).

Please guide me to solve this.

Code as follows:

in class:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     field1: "",
     field2: "",
    };
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    let field1= event.target.value;
    // console.log("coming1", field1); // given input is showing here
    this.setState({ field2: field1 });
    // let x=this.setState({ field2: field1 });
    // console.log("Output",x); //undefined 
};
```

The following is rendered input fields in the form:

```
 field1: <Field type="text"
                component={TextField}
                placeholder="enter in field1"
                name="field1"
                required
                onChange={this.handleChange} />

 field2:  <Field type="text"
                 component={TextField}
                 placeholder="value comes from field1"
                 name="field2"
                 value={this.state.field2}
                 required />
```

Edit1: This is not just like exact direct replica. i'll slice some value from the field1 and replicate it in field2

Comment: You probably just been to bind your event: https://www.pmichaels.net/2019/07/27/react-tips-2-binding-an-event-handler/

Comment: setState is a async event.  so your console log is undefined.

Comment: this.setState({
    someState: obj
}, () => {
    // some console log or event you want to fire after state is set
});

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code out. See it work here: https://jsfiddle.net/qsy78xhk/1/

You simply need to change it to this:

```
    field1: <Field type="text"
                component={TextField}
                placeholder="enter in field1"
                name="field1"
                required
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />

    field2: <Field
                type="text"
                component={TextField}
                placeholder="value comes from field1"
                name="field2"
                value={this.state.field2}
                required />
```

Comment: sorry, it is field2 only. Please check.same undefined coming as output

Comment: Hi @RamlalS, updated it to give the solution. There's also a working sample of it.

Comment: @AlgefAlmocera I don't see the need to bind the `this` in your example yes but, in his post he has used the fat arrow which references global scope and need not bind `this`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `field1` state in your handleChange:

```
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({ field1: event.target.value });
}

<Field
   type="text"
   component={TextField}
   placeholder="enter in field1"
   name="field1"
   value={this.state.field1}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   required
/>
<Field
   type="text"
   component={TextField}
   placeholder="value comes from field1"
   name="field2"
   value={this.state.field1}
   required
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should bind both values to the state. Because changes in the UI need to be reflected in state.

```js
handleChange = (event) => {
    let field1Value= event.target.value;
    this.setState({ field1: field1Value, field2: field1Value });
};
```

For the render

```js
 <Field type="text"
      component={TextField}
      placeholder="enter in field1"
      value={this.state.field1}
      name="field1"
      required
      onChange={this.handleChange} />

 <Field type="text"
     component={TextField}
     placeholder="value comes from field1"
     name="field2"
     value={this.state.field2}
     required />
```

If you just want to see a copy of the data, change the value of field2 to `{this.state.field1}` so you can exclude the additional field2 property in state.

Comment: still coming field2 as undefined. any other idea?

Comment: From the above snippet I see you are logging the state just after calling `setState` this will result in the value to be undefined. As @LogicBlower mentioned `setState` is asynchronous and won't be reflected immediately. To see if it is working just log in the submit handler or somwhere else.